# Is there a convergence for the series $ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-y*i)^i}{i!} $?

Tags: calculus, statistics, convergence-divergence

The following series converges to exponential.

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} = e^x$

Is the convergence of the following series known?

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x - y*i)^i}{i!}$

Comment: There are too many questions in this question.  These should be two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(x-yn)^n}{n!}\right|^{1/n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\,\frac xn-y\,\right|\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{(n!)^{1/n}}\\
&=|y|\,e\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
then the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) says that the series converges if $|y|\lt\frac1e$.

---

**Regarding the Limit**

By the [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^n}{n!}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\[9pt]
&=e
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Isn't the kth term $(x-yk)^k*(k!)^{-1}$ not $(yk-x)^k*(k!)^{-1}$?

Comment: If one doesn't go to $0$, the other doesn't either.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out how $\frac{(yk)^k}{k!} = \frac{y(k+1)^k}{k^k}$

Comment: @arash: I was misapplying the [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). I have fixed the answer.

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks for the edit. In our problem $|y|<e^{-1}$. More specifically, we are searching for the convergence of the $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(y*k - y* i)^i}{i!}$ where $y = -re^{-r}$

Answer (score 0):

If you do the same as in my [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992494/is-there-a-convergence-for-the-series-sum-i-0-infty-fracx-iii/1992657#1992657), you should arrive to $$A=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=-e y+\frac{e y}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ and then $\cdots$.